# Given this graph from Wikipedia concerning the cosmogenic origin of each element, how are Lithium, Beryllium, and Boron formed from cosmic rays?

Tags: elements, cosmic-rays, nucleosynthesis

So I found [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-process) from another answer, and it's math is way above me but the gist is that some elements heavier than Iron can form in a star, but this path is not the primary source of these elements (Super novae are). I then found this periodic table in the article. It shows the possible sources of elements, but labels 3 elements, Lithium, Beryllium, and Boron, as originating from Cosmic rays. From everything I've read, elements could only fuse during the big bang, or in stars. Cosmic rays are powerful, but no where near the power required for large scale fusion. If this is the case, how could these three elements be formed exclusively from cosmic rays?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do supernovae produce an appreciable amount of lithium?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197920/)

Comment: The "duplicate" has absolutely nothing to do with forming Li, Be and B from cosmic rays.

Comment: By *cosmogenic origin* you mean the presence of these elements in the Universe or their presence on Earth? This might be important for deciding whether question is on topic here or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this graph is referring to [Cosmic ray spallation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray_spallation) which can produce lithium, beryllium, and boron isotopes which would not be present (in as large quantities) from other forms of nucleosynthesis. However, the proportion of these elements that come from spallation seems to be a bit complicated and I won't pretend to understand it. It is discussed in eg.  [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/668701/why-are-lithium-7-and-boron-11-respectively-more-abundant-than-lithium-6-a?rq=1).