# Where is lithium in universe?

Tags: big-bang, elements

In the theory of big-bang  elements were  formed in a particular order. Firstly hydrogen and in last iron formed. But at third no. Lithium was formed which should be present in enormous amount in universe. So where did it go?

Comment: There is a similar post [Why is there a scarcity of lithium?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11154/96054) Also, scarcity of lithium in the universe is a well-researched problem, you can find a lot more interesting articles by simply searching for "lithium in universe".